# Fail to load files

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I had issue with one Mac app, my college and developer of app don't have this issue.

MacOS 10.15.5, i can't load more than 122 files as group. If add one file as 123 app can't load. It showed by random way *** fail to open, this file is fine.
*I reinstalled new macos, issue doesn't solve it.*

Here is log file of app: lines normal like first one, the others many lines like second one.
[image: photo of log file]

```
Found dictionary:/Users/**/Downloads/pro/****, added to list
    Open file failed, reason:No such file or directory
    Open file failed, reason:No such file or directory
    Open file failed, reason:Too many open files
    Open file failed, reason:Too many open files
    Fail to load dict:/Users/**/Downloads/pro/*****, Error:Fail to open file
```

Files is ok, if i opened only one file is ok.

**The issue only when loading all files together as group.**

I appreciate for helping.

Comment: What code is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

[App link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mdict/id389083586)
When you the folder of dict contain many files. If less than 122, it works fine like charm. But if add 123 or more, app can't load any thing. “Failed to open ***”, this file not corrupt, the issue with app.

My friend don't have this issue. My mac now has new system, i reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem related to limit open file by system.

Solution:
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000

And then open app.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution:

ref: https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits/

1. Download this two file: https://github.com/wilsonmar/mac-setup/blob/master/configs/limit.maxfiles.plist

https://github.com/wilsonmar/mac-setup/blob/master/configs/limit.maxproc.plist

1. Copy and Paste this two file in folder /Library/LaunchDaemons/
2. In terminal write this code:

> ```
> sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
> sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist
> ```

Enter, will ask for user password.

3. In terminal, write:

```
sudo ulimit -n 65536 200000
```

4. Restart, i will work like a charm! Enjoy